# Как сделать вывод персонажей при помощи SWAPI?

Tags: javascript

Такая ситуация - мне надо при помощи SWAPI вывести наименование планеты и тех, кто на ней появлялся. Вывод наименований планет я сделал. А как сделать вывод персонажей?

В API на них стоит просто ссылка. Пример кода планеты из API:

```
{
            "name": "Yavin IV", 
            "rotation_period": "24", 
            "orbital_period": "4818", 
            "diameter": "10200", 
            "climate": "temperate, tropical", 
            "gravity": "1 standard", 
            "terrain": "jungle, rainforests", 
            "surface_water": "8", 
            "population": "1000", 
            "residents": [], 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T11:37:19.144000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.421000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/"
},
```

Для вывода персонажей используется API с другим URL. Как его можно "привязать" и выводить вместе с наименованием планеты?

Сам код вывода названия планет:

```
function getStarWarsPlanets(progress, url = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets', planets = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200)  {
          throw `${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`;
        }
        response.json().then(data => { 
          planets = planets.concat(data.results);

          if(data.next) {
            progress && progress(planets);
            getStarWarsPlanets(progress, data.next, planets).then(resolve).catch(reject)
          } else {
            resolve(planets);
          }
        }).catch(reject);
    }).catch(reject));
}

function progressCallback(planets) {
}

getStarWarsPlanets(progressCallback)
  .then(planets => {
    document.writeln(planets.map(p => p.name))
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Получить json по этому url, и выводить, в чем трабл?

Comment: В том то и дело, я только начинаю изучить и не знаю, как это реализовать